# Field can be converted to local variable

Tags: java

I have this error: Field can be converted to local variable.
for **preparedStatement**

```
package game;

import java.sql.*;

public class db {

    private Connection connection;
    private PreparedStatement preparedStatement;

    public db() throws SQLException,ClassNotFoundException {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/riverraider";
            String user = "root";
            String pass = "146155";
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
    }

    public String select(String username, String password) throws Exception
    {
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `username`=? AND `password`=? ");
        preparedStatement.setLong(1, Long.parseLong(username));
        preparedStatement.setLong(1, Long.parseLong(password));
        ResultSet result =   preparedStatement.executeQuery();


        while (result.next()!=false){
            System.out.println("Username or password is incorrect.");
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: also note that keeping those connections open indefinitely, with the possibility of creating new ones while the existing one is still there, isn't the best design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, the error/warning is just stemming from your declaring the variable `preparedStatement` as a class level variable, when it can just be a variable local to the `select()` method with the same effect.  Try removing that declaration from the class level, and instead using this version of `select()`:

```
public String select(String username, String password) throws Exception {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";
    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setLong(1, Long.parseLong(username));
    ps.setLong(1, Long.parseLong(password));

    ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();

    while (result.next() != false) {
        System.out.println("Username or password is incorrect.");
    }
}
```

I also tidied up your code a bit to make it easier to read.  You don't need backticks around your column names, because they are not reserved keywords (nor should they be).

Note: I'm not sure that your username and password columns are actually numeric.  More likely, I would expect at least the username to be text of some sort.  But, this would result in an error other than the one you reported in your question.